# Can the new Azure web application firewall scope the ftp port by IP address?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-firewall

I am thinking of migrating from a dedicated server to Azure Web Application Service but when I did a free trial about a year ago you could not scope the ftp port by IP address leaving it open to all IPs or computers to try to login. The question is - can the new Azure web application firewall scope the ftp port by IP address?

Comment: As I known ,Azure Web App doesn't have firewall. I'm not aware of your question. Could post more detials for this?

Comment: Bit late sorry but I can see WAF as part of the Application Gateway system now I have reinstated my account without an answer to my question from sales. I'm not sure if this is just for Virtual Machines.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to my problem. You can now totally disable FTP.

Comment: Please post the solution